# php remove QUERY_STRING variable

Tags: php

i have this function that should remove part of a query string:

```
if(!function_exists("remove_querystring_var")) {
    function remove_querystring_var($url, $key) {
        $url = preg_replace('/(.*)(?|&)' . $key . '=[^&]+?(&)(.*)/i', '$1$2$4', $url . '&');
        $url = substr($url, 0, -1);
        return ($url);
    }
}
```

i have ahref links like:

```
<a href="link.php?<?php echo $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]; ?>">link</a>
```

but i need to be able to remove `?pagenum=X` (X = a page number)

Comment: `parse_str()` + `http_build_query()`

Comment: So does your `remove_querystring_var` function work?  Not work?  What's the question here?

Comment: Btw, `if(!function_exists("remove_querystring_var")) {` looks like fixing consequences not the roots.

Comment: Does $url = preg_replace('?pagenum=X', ''); not work or is that not what you needed to do?

Comment: locks very [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could just

```
unset($_GET['pagenum']);
```

and

```
<a href="link.php?<?= http_build_query($_GET) ?>">link</a>
```

Code would potentially look like:

```
<?php

// $_GET looks like: array('foo'=>'bar','pagenum'=>5,'abc'=>'xyz')

unset($_GET['pagenum']);

// now $_GET looks like: array('foo'=>'bar','abc'=>'xyz')

// so http_build_query($_GET) will look like: foo=bar&abc=xyz
?>


<a href="link.php?<?php echo http_build_query($_GET) ?>">link</a>
```

Comment: how do i use unset in a href link ?

Comment: you don't, you unset the GET variable before building a new query string, ill edit the answer to make it more clear